# Can't initialize PowerShell session in VSCode for Mac

Tags: macos, powershell, visual-studio-code

Briefly, I installed PowerShell via Homebrew.  Then I installed the extension in VSCode (also restarted VSCode).  When VSCode picks up that I'm working on a PowerShell script it tries to start a PowerShell session. (PowerShell integrated terminal)

```
PowerShell Integrated Console

An error occurred while starting PowerShell Editor Services:

The term 'chmod' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
   at System.Management.Automation.ExceptionHandlingOps.CheckActionPreference(FunctionContext funcContext, Exception exception)
   at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.ActionCallInstruction`2.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
   at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
   at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
   at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.Interpreter.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
   at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.LightLambda.RunVoid1[T0](T0 arg0)
   at System.Management.Automation.PSScriptCmdlet.RunClause(Action`1 clause, Object dollarUnderbar, Object inputToProcess)
   at System.Management.Automation.PSScriptCmdlet.DoEndProcessing()
   at System.Management.Automation.CommandProcessorBase.Complete()
```

I get that `chmod` means something somewhere is trying to change some file permission.  But I have no idea what it is.  Maybe I can change the permissions myself and then PowerShell will finally start?

If I look at the extension logs I have this:

```
1/20/2020 9:54:39 AM [NORMAL] - Visual Studio Code v1.41.1 64-bit
1/20/2020 9:54:39 AM [NORMAL] - PowerShell Extension v2020.1.0
1/20/2020 9:54:39 AM [NORMAL] - Operating System: MacOS 64-bit
1/20/2020 9:54:39 AM [NORMAL] - Path specified by 'powerShellExePath' setting - '' - not found, reverting to default PowerShell path.
1/20/2020 9:54:39 AM [NORMAL] - Language server starting --
1/20/2020 9:54:39 AM [NORMAL] -     exe: /usr/local/bin/pwsh
1/20/2020 9:54:39 AM [NORMAL] -     args: /Users/me/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode.powershell-2020.1.0/modules/PowerShellEditorServices/Start-EditorServices.ps1 -HostName 'Visual Studio Code Host' -HostProfileId 'Microsoft.VSCode' -HostVersion '2020.1.0' -AdditionalModules @('PowerShellEditorServices.VSCode') -BundledModulesPath '/Users/me/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode.powershell-2020.1.0/modules' -EnableConsoleRepl -LogLevel 'Normal' -LogPath '/Users/me/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode.powershell-2020.1.0/logs/1579532079-da336a1a-b41b-4ae4-8d54-c10e5e98d3fc1579532032267/EditorServices.log' -SessionDetailsPath '/Users/me/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode.powershell-2020.1.0/sessions/PSES-VSCode-72218-307401' -FeatureFlags @()
1/20/2020 9:54:40 AM [NORMAL] - powershell.exe started, pid: 13196
1/20/2020 9:56:39 AM [NORMAL] - Language server startup failed.
1/20/2020 9:56:39 AM [ERROR] - The language service could not be started: 
1/20/2020 9:56:39 AM [ERROR] - Timed out waiting for session file to appear.
1/20/2020 9:59:47 AM [NORMAL] - powershell.exe terminated or terminal UI was closed
```

I do see in the logs my `powerShellExePath` is blank, but I don't have any idea what to set that up as (or if that's the issue).

PowerShell by itself works fine.  If in the terminal I punch in `pwsh path/to/file/helloWorld.ps1` it will run and print out as expected.

Any ideas appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This drives me nuts every time there's an update... luckily, the fix is easy.

```
~/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode.powershell-2020.1.0/modules/PowerShellEditorServices/Start-EditorServices.ps1
```

Around line 272, change

```
chmod $DEFAULT_USER_MODE $PipeFile
```

to

```
/bin/chmod $DEFAULT_USER_MODE $PipeFile
```

Comment: Ha!  I actually eventually figured this out on my own (took quite awhile) but forgot to update here.  Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

This situation can be specific to macOS with a Windows-based [profile script](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_profiles?view=powershell-7.1).

I found that for the profile script I was using, it was initially designed for Windows, and as part of the profile initialization it would set `$env:PSModulePath`. However, it would use a Windows path separator `;`, versus `:` used on macOS. Therefore, the last path would get combined with the added one, and that last path happens to be the modules folder of the PowerShell VS Code extension...

`/Users/bart/.local/share/powershell/Modules:/usr/local/share/powershell/Modules:/Users/bart/.dotnet/tools/.store/powershell/7.1.4/powershell/7.1.4/tools/net5.0/any/unix/Modules:/Users/bart/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode.powershell-2021.9.0/modules;/Users/bart/custom/path`

The solution was to update the Windows-only line with a [cross-platform compatible PSModulePath assignment](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/module/modifying-the-psmodulepath-installation-path?view=powershell-7.1#to-add-locations-to-the-psmodulepath-variable):

```
$env:PSModulePath = $env:PSModulePath + "$([System.IO.Path]::PathSeparator)$MyModulePath"
```