# powershell integrated console hanging on macos

Tags: macos, powershell, visual-studio-code

First I had this problem: [Can't initialize PowerShell session in VSCode for Mac](https://superuser.com/questions/1518697/cant-initialize-powershell-session-in-vscode-for-mac)

I edited the script and now its not throwing that error and it just hangs and I cant run any commands:
[image]

I can see that it is hanging on: `$editorServicesHost.WaitForCompletion()`

Looking at the $LogPath file the script writes I see this error:

```
2020-03-01 09:37:55.677 [NORMAL] tid:9 in 'StartLogging' D:\a\1\s\src\PowerShellEditorServices.Host\EditorServicesHost.cs: line 183

    PowerShell Editor Services Host v1.13.3.0 starting (PID 77480

      Host application details:

        Name:      Visual Studio Code Host
        Version:   2020.1.0
        ProfileId: Microsoft.VSCode
        Arch:      X64

      Operating system details:

        Version: Darwin 18.6.0 Darwin Kernel Version 18.6.0: Thu Apr 25 23:16:27 PDT 2019; root:xnu-4903.261.4~2/RELEASE_X86_64
        Arch:    X64

      Build information:

        Version: 
        Origin:  VSTS
        Date:    2020-01-13T23:11:01


2020-03-01 09:37:55.699 [NORMAL] tid:9 in 'StartLanguageService' D:\a\1\s\src\PowerShellEditorServices.Host\EditorServicesHost.cs: line 202
    Language service started, type = NamedPipe, endpoint =  InOut pipe: PSES_esjyfps3.oyj

2020-03-01 09:37:55.706 [NORMAL] tid:9 in 'StartDebugService' D:\a\1\s\src\PowerShellEditorServices.Host\EditorServicesHost.cs: line 279
    Debug service started, type = NamedPipe, endpoint =  InOut pipe: PSES_solbdwjg.nfn

2020-03-01 09:37:57.114 [ERROR] tid:4 in 'ListenForConnection' D:\a\1\s\src\PowerShellEditorServices.Protocol\MessageProtocol\Channel\NamedPipeServerListener.cs: line 155
    Exception: An unhandled exception occurred while listening for a named pipe client connection

    System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed'. The system cannot find the file specified.

    File name: 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed'
       at Microsoft.PowerShell.EditorServices.Protocol.MessageProtocol.MessageWriter..ctor(Stream outputStream, IMessageSerializer messageSerializer, ILogger logger)
       at Microsoft.PowerShell.EditorServices.Protocol.MessageProtocol.Channel.NamedPipeServerChannel.Initialize(IMessageSerializer messageSerializer)
       at Microsoft.PowerShell.EditorServices.Protocol.MessageProtocol.Channel.ServerListenerBase`1.OnClientConnect(TChannel channel)
       at Microsoft.PowerShell.EditorServices.Protocol.MessageProtocol.Channel.NamedPipeServerListener.<<ListenForConnection>b__9_0>d.MoveNext()
```

Comment: you likely otta add the versions of VSCode, the powershell addon, and your version of MacOS to you Question. [*grin*]

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading powershell 6.0.3 -> 6.2.4 solved the issue